# How to set action for the bottom UIBarButtonItems in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem

I have an application where there are two items at the bottom bar in a view controller. One item is at the left and another one is at middle of the bottom bar. Now, what I like to do that when someone click on the middle item of the bottom bar, it will redirect the user to the website. how to get the action for the middle item of the bottom bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a UIBarButtonItem, it has a `target` property and an `action` property, These configure what it does when tapped — it sends the `action` to the `target`. In theory, you *should* have configured these when you created the UIBarButtonItem.